# Microsoft Account change for Windows Registry

Tags: windows, microsoft-account

Using my Microsoft Account, I have registered for the Windows Insider program, but I never used it.

I never installed a Windows Insider OS, and now I want to unregister from Windows Insider program. When I go to that website, it does not load, it merely hangs, it spins and spins. If you click these links, it will load the inital website front page, but if you follow their instructions and sign into your MS Account, it will freeze.
 
https://insider.windows.com/en-us/
https://insider.windows.com/en-us/register
https://insider.windows.com/en-us/leave-program
 
I have tried this in 2 different browsers, I have disabled all my ad blockers, and all other extensions. I tried it on 2 different operating systems, I also tried signing in and out, I also closed and reopened my browsers and the result was exactly the same.

How do I get to successfully manually discontinue my subscription to the  Windows Insider program. Microsoft's website to leave the Windows Insider program simply does not work under any circumstances.

If you can, please help me with my Microsoft Account to manually discontinue my subscription to the  Windows Insider program so I can get off their email list.

Comment: It's impressive how well posters ignore repeated plain statements. I said several times I do not have a Windows Insider version of Windows. I am not asking how to fix a Windows OS issue, or how to change a device, a software, or a system setting. Do you know the difference between Microsoft and Windows? I am asking about my Microsoft Account, not Windows. Please respond if you understand that.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, so you are unlikely to get responses; clarifications to your question should be in the form of an [edit].  Indicating the version and build you are running will make what version of Windows you are running all that much easier to digest. **Worth pointing out that the [website](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/leave-program) is designed to "leave the Insider Preview Program" on devices running an applicable build.** This is why it does nothing on a non-Insider Preview build of Windows. I can tell by the way the website is functing it's suppose to open Settings.

Comment: This site answers questions about Windows, but not about your Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

A Microsoft Account has not and does not register your device in the Windows Insider program. This is a misconception at the beginning of your post. You must overtly register for the Windows Insider Program and a Microsoft Account is not necessary to do this.

If you have been registered in the Insider Program (even though you have not used it), then Insider registration is part of Windows 10 / 11 Update. Go to Updates and see Insider Program on the right hand side. You can join or leave the program here. If you have not ever installed an insider version, you can leave and there are no side effects.

> I never installed a Windows Insider OS, and now I want to unregister
> from Windows Insider program. .....  How do I get to successfully
> manually discontinue my subscription to the
>  >  Windows Insider program.

This is more difficult.

(1) If you never installed an Insider Version, then Settings, Update, Windows Insider, Leave Program works.  I have used this.

(2) If (1) does not work, then you or an error unbeknownst to you installed an insider version.

If this is true, that is, you cannot leave the program, then you need to back up everything and reinstall Windows.  This is very clear in the Insider Program terms.

For certain, the issue you have does not have anything to do with using a Microsoft Account. Never has.

I posted a screen shot of leaving the program

[image: Windows 10 11 Leave Insider Program]